# Autodesk Forge Document Approve Status

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We are using Autodesk BIM360 Docs to manage our drawings, and as well review workflows are used in our project. Now we get a request to use Forge API to copy files that are approved to our local storage. Everything seems good except that we cannot find a forge API with which we can get the approve status of each document.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before consulting our engineering team, I would like to double check the `approve status` you mentioned is the document status of newly introduced `approval workflow` of the BIM360 Docs, isn't it? Ref: https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Managing-Review-and-Approval-Workflows-BIM-360-Document-Management-2018#video

Comment: Thanks Eason, Yes, i am referring to Approval Workflow of BIM360 Doc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that there is no API available to fetch approve status currently. Please keep your eyes on [Forge blog announcements](https://forge.autodesk.com/categories/announcements) and [BIM360 roadmap](https://blogs.autodesk.com/bim360-roadmap/) for updating. Once it gets supported we will post here. Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this? There does not seem to be any road map anymore (at least it is completely empty) and forge api documentation seems also out dated as well. Review status exists in response to get file version endpoint but it does not have correct value. it is always 'NOT_IN_REVIEW', despite it was.